# Reading Wikipedia through Tor : will my life be safer this way?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity

When reading Wikipedia, which benefits arise of doing it through Tor versus doing it by the common default web way?

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly ok as Wikipedia doesn't require javascript, you can just turn it off.

Using Tor, Wikipedia cannot see your home address and using Tor as TorBrowser, it couldn't track and fingerprint you.

But I believe Wikipedia block Tor and open proxies IPs from editing its pages, so if you are going to edit anything there, you should use a non-blacklisted IP of a VPN, SSH proxy, Shadowsocks and so on.

Comment: I believe you did not understood the question: "which benefits arise of doing it through Tor versus doing it by the common default web way".

Comment: The question is so obvious: Wikipedia cannot see the user's IP address and couldn't fingerprint your default browser. I said "couldn't" because Wikipedia is not employing any tracking mechanism so far.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah It's ok, I edited my answer.

Comment: "Using Tor, Wikipedia cannot see your home address and using Tor as TorBrowser, it couldn't track and fingerprint you." So, no benefit for me. After all, I'm already a Wikipedia editor, an, as such, Wikipedia already has far more information about me than it could get by mean ways (if it was evil).

Comment: You did not mention anything about my employer or my ISP knowing which articles I'm reading. Is that because I'm using modern HTTPS cyphers?

Comment: If you're not using any cryptographic mechanism/method in DNS, they can see that you're reading Wikipedia, but not the full URL of the page.